# How to align buttons after text in list, so they are in the same column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm not very fluent in web-design. I'm trying to show a list for downloading software. Each list item contains a text followed by one or more Bootstrap buttons. I want buttons to be aligned as in a column, right after the largest text. Something like (do not pay attention to other spacings but left button alignment, it is just a draft):

[image: Sample]

A sample of my current code is as follows:

```css
li > .column-align {
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  height: 50px;
}

li {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
  <li>
    Software 1
    <span class="column-align">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://example.com/download.exe">Download</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://example.com/download.exe">Download demo</a>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    Software 2
    <span class="column-align">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://example.com/download.exe">Download</a>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    Software 4 (Special Edition)
    <span class="column-align">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://example.com/download.exe">Download</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://example.com/download.exe">Download demo</a>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    Software 5
    <span class="column-align">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://example.com/download.exe">Download</a>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This code more-or-less works, but as the page is generated dynamically, I want to avoid fixing the left-distance (position, margin...), so it can adjust to text / style. How can I do it correctly?

Also, and as secondary question: I've had to fix the line height so buttons are not covered, but, in addition to be hardcoded, makes the buttons not to be correctly aligned vertically. Is there any way to avoid such ugly workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using bootstrap grid as in row and col classes

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
  <li class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">Software 1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://example.com/download.exe">Download</a></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://example.com/download.exe">Download demo</a></div>
  </li>
  <li class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">Software 2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://example.com/download.exe">Download</a></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://example.com/download.exe">Download demo</a></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `flexbox` for this task.

```css
ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
   <li>
      Software 1
   </li>
   <li>
      Software 2
   </li>
   <li>
      Software 4 (Special Edition)
   </li>
   <li>
      Software 5
   </li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>
     <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://example.com/download.exe">Download</a>
     <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://example.com/download.exe">Download demo</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://example.com/download.exe">Download</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://example.com/download.exe">Download</a>
     <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://example.com/download.exe">Download demo</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://example.com/download.exe">Download</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't keep together text and buttons if the viewport is shrinked :(

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use **flexbox** and to consider your `ul` as a "module" (that I call `software`) and put it in a col-x-x's div which follows all the rules of the bootstrap grid (if you do so, maybe it is more usable).

In this exemple, I used a `col-sm-12`.

```css
.software {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.software li{
  margin:5px 5px 15px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  text-align:center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* you can change the min-width of this @media query as you want, depends of your layout */

@media (min-width: 480px) { 
  .software li{
    flex-direction:row;
    text-align:left;
  }

  .software li .title{
    width:30%; /*also here, change this % as you want*/
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">

      <ul class="software">
        <li>
          <span class="title">Software 1</span>
          <span class="column-align">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://example.com/download.exe">Download</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://example.com/download.exe">Download demo</a>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="title">Software 2</span>
          <span class="column-align">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://example.com/download.exe">Download</a>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="title">Software 4 (Special Edition)</span>
          <span class="column-align">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://example.com/download.exe">Download</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://example.com/download.exe">Download demo</a>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="title">Software 5</span>
          <span class="column-align">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://example.com/download.exe">Download</a>
          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```